# Is there any way to use ASP.NET CORE MVC and WEB API together?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.NET CORE and interested in how MVC and WEB API could be combined together? For example is there any way to use WEB API for back-end and MVC for front-end? The application should be simple CRUD app.

Comment: You can use whatever you want at the same time. Usually with MVC you still have some Web APIs in the background.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Which should I create MVC or API project at start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to create an MVC application.

Just create an api-controller inside and you have both!

A web api is just MVC, without the V, that is a *model* and a *controller*, no *view*.